# MATLAB: modify arima model coefficients

Tags: matlab, arima, arma

I want to modify ARIMA model coefficients (MATLAB). I estimated my model using this code:

```
mdl_1 = arima(2, 1, 2);
estMdl_1 = estimate(mdl_1, data1');
```

MATLAB output:

```
 ARIMA(2,1,2) Model:
    --------------------
    Conditional Probability Distribution: Gaussian

                                  Standard          t     
     Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
    -----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
     Constant     -0.0251424     0.0207631       -1.21092
        AR{1}     -0.0111471     0.0720374      -0.154741
        AR{2}       0.662378     0.0498501        13.2874
        MA{1}       0.259267      0.153002        1.69454
        MA{2}      -0.600908      0.111204       -5.40366
     Variance      0.0833621     0.0122521        6.80391
```

And now I want to modify this values in order to see what happens with the residuals. Unfortunately, MATLAB does not support modifying the estimated model directly. So I use this code:

```
my_mdl1 = arima('Constant',-0.0251424,'AR',{-0.0111471,0.662378},...
'MA',{0.259267,-0.600908},'Variance',0.0833621);
```

As you can see, I created an arima model which equals to estimated model mentioned above.
After that I trying to infer my residuals for model **my_mdl1** but they are not equals to residuls of the estimated model. Why? 
Also I tried to look at the values of variables. The values of the estimated model (by MATLAB):

```
  estMdl_1 = 

ARIMA(2,1,2) Model:
--------------------
Distribution: Name = 'Gaussian'
           P: 3
           D: 1
           Q: 2
    Constant: -0.0251424
          AR: {-0.0111471 0.662378} at Lags [1 2]
         SAR: {}
          MA: {0.259267 -0.600908} at Lags [1 2]
         SMA: {}
    Variance: 0.0833621
```

The values of the model created by me:

```
my_mdl1 = 

ARIMA(2,0,2) Model:
--------------------
Distribution: Name = 'Gaussian'
           P: 2
           D: 0
           Q: 2
    Constant: -0.0251424
          AR: {-0.0111471 0.662378} at Lags [1 2]
         SAR: {}
          MA: {0.259267 -0.600908} at Lags [1 2]
         SMA: {}
    Variance: 0.0833621
```

As you can see, there is some difference. P, D, Q are not equals. Maybe it's a problem, or not? Unfortunately I don't know, how to edit P, D, Q values :(

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I found the answer! [Here it is](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arma-models.html).

And the decision for my case:

```
my_mdl1 = arima(2, 1, 2);
my_mdl1.Constant = -0.0251424;
my_mdl1.AR = {-0.0111471,0.662378};
my_mdl1.MA = {0.259267,-0.600908};
my_mdl1.Variance = 0.0833621;
```

It works! I can change the coefficients and receive proper residuals.